# impact force of a vehicle moving at constant speed or a decelerating vehicle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

which one has a higher impact force?
A vehicle moving at 5m/s and hitting a wall or the same vehicle moving at higher speed, but brakes and hits the wall at 5m/s?
I hope this makes sense :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens before impact is irrelevant. Also note that all real impacts happen during a finite amount of time. Just before impact both cars have the same kinetic energy, which will go to zero during impact, and be converted to heat, sound, and damage in general, assuming a total inelastic collision. If the car is still braking during impact, then strictly speaking, some of the force stopping the car will be applied by the brakes, and the rest will be applied to the body of the car by whatever barrier the car hits. Consequently, no brakes means all energy converted to body damage, and braking means some energy converted to heating/wearing the brakes and tires. So there should be slightly less "damage" to the car if you brake during impact.

Answer (score 0):

The impact happens so fast that deceleration doesn't matter. The impact speed is the key variable here.

Any change in speed due to the brakes during the impact will be orders of magnitude smaller than the change of speed due to the impact.

Comment: so the damage done in both cases is equal?

Comment: Is it braking before it hits the wall? Or simultaneously with hitting the wall?

Comment: @user45664 It doesn't matter. The _OP_ stated the impact speed is the same.

Comment: @jay72 --Got It.